# iOS quaternion for X and Y

Tags: ios, gyroscope

it's been a couple of days trying to figure this out with no luck, sometimes it works and others doesn't so I think I'm doing something wrong,

What I want to do is to make iPhone act as a laser for a presentation screen (using appleTV)

So that pointing the device to somewhere of the screen it actually points there.

I'm trying to use the CMAttitude.yaw and Pitch to calibrate it, so the user first defines top left and bottom right, and then get the scale values between them so get the actual position,

However, I always get different values, and I can't compute a stable scale

[image]

What I'm doing now is:

1. Start motionmanager

   ```
       mMotionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
   mMotionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = .02;

   //[mMotionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
   [mMotionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical];
   ```
2. Calibrate in two steps

   ```
   if(mCalibrationStatus == 0){
   mMinX = [self getYaw];
   mMinY = [self getPitch];

   mCalibrationStatus++;

   NSLog(@"MinX %f -- MinY: %f", mMinX,mMinY);
   ```

   }
   else if(mCalibrationStatus == 1){
       mMaxX = [self getYaw];
       mMaxY = [self getPitch];
       mCalibrationStatus++;
       NSLog(@"MaxX %f -- MaxY: %f", mMaxX,mMaxY);
   }
3. Compute the position

   float rangeX = mMaxX + mMinX;
       float sX     = [self getYaw]/rangeX;

   ```
   float rangeY = mMaxY + mMinY;
   float sY     = [self getPitch]/rangeY;

   if(pShouldDebug){
       NSLog(@"RangeX [%f, %f, %f] ==> %f",mMinX, [self getYaw], mMaxX, rangeX);
       NSLog(@"ScaleX: %f",sX);

       NSLog(@"RangeY [%f, %f, %f] ==> %f",mMinY,[self getPitch], mMaxY, rangeY);
       NSLog(@"ScaleY: %f",sY);
   }

   return CGPointMake(sX*mScreenSize.width, mScreenSize.height - sY*mScreenSize.height);
   ```

And to get the yaw and roll:

```
    -(float) getYaw{
    return mMotionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw;
    //return mMotionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion.x;
}

-(float) getPitch{
    return mMotionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch;
    //return mMotionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion.y;
}
```

And it only works sometimes... so I assume the idea is right but the way to get the angles is not good..

I would really appreciate any help here, Thank you so much!